# Multi-threading Julia shows error with enumerate iterator

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, iterator, julia, enumerate

Why does this very simple code result in an error in Julia 1.1?

```
Threads.@threads for (index,value) in enumerate([0.1,0.2,0.3])
    println(value^index)

end
```

The error shown is:

```
Error thrown in threaded loop on thread 0: MethodError(f=typeof(Base.unsafe_getindex)(), args=(Base.Iterators.Enumerate{Array{Float64, 1}}(itr=Array{Float64, (3,)}[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), 1), world=0x00000000000069dc)
Error thrown in threaded loop on thread 1: MethodError(f=typeof(Base.unsafe_getindex)(), args=(Base.Iterators.Enumerate{Array{Float64, 1}}(itr=Array{Float64, (3,)}[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), 3), world=0x00000000000069dc)
```

I want to use `Threads.@threads` with more complicated codes where I use the `enumerate` iterator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Threads.@threads` marco expects an array to iterate over only. [Here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/threaded-for-loop-over-arbitrary-indexable-objects/26957) you have a link to a topic on Discourse on it.

So currently you have to iterate over indices only using e.g. `axes` or e.g. `collect` `eachindex` (which is not ideal).

So in your case this would be:

```
vec = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
Threads.@threads for index in axes(vec, 1)
    println(vec[index]^index)
end
```

or

```
Threads.@threads for (index,value) in collect(enumerate([0.1,0.2,0.3]))
    println(value^index)
end
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I have then to be careful with iterators. I think it will be the same with the `eachrow()` iterator, with which I had troubles too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - `eachrow` in Base is a `Generator`. But for example `eachrow` in DataFrames.jl is an `AbstractVector` so it would work.

Comment: Thank you for your useful explanation :-) As always :-)

Comment: Also note that under Julia 1.1 using `println` is not recommended as IO is not thread safe. Use Julia 1.3 for this, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-1.3/NEWS.md.